# Оптимизировать case запрос (sql, oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Прошу помочь оптимизировать условие по case, чтобы не расписывать when для каждого месяца

Приходится расписывать так для каждого месяца потому что например для февр. нет значений по

[image: На скрине видно отсутствие значений для определенных месяцев]

RT0M_23M2
RT0M_23M3
REQ_SALES_FTTB_23M2
REQ_SALES_FMC_23M2
REQ_SALES_FTTB_23M3
REQ_SALES_FMC_23M3

```
case    
    when CALL_MONTH = date'2023-02-01'
        then round((sum(CONNECTED)*(avg(REV0_23M1)/avg(RT0M_23M1))) * ( (avg(RT0M_23M1) )/ ( avg(REQ_SALES_FTTB_23M1 + REQ_SALES_FMC_23M1) )))
    when CALL_MONTH = date'2023-03-01'
            then round((sum(CONNECTED)*(avg(REV0_23M1)/avg(RT0M_23M1))) * ((avg(RT0M_23M1) + avg(RT0M_23M2) )/(avg(REQ_SALES_FTTB_23M1 + REQ_SALES_FMC_23M1)+avg(REQ_SALES_FTTB_23M2+REQ_SALES_FMC_23M2) )))      
    when CALL_MONTH between to_date ('01.04.2023','dd.mm.yyyy') and to_date ('01.09.2023','dd.mm.yyyy') 
          then round((sum(CONNECTED)*(avg(REV0_23M1)/avg(RT0M_23M1))) * ((avg(RT0M_23M1) + avg(RT0M_23M2)+avg(RT0M_23M3))/(avg(REQ_SALES_FTTB_23M1 + REQ_SALES_FMC_23M1)+avg(REQ_SALES_FTTB_23M2+REQ_SALES_FMC_23M2) + avg(REQ_SALES_FTTB_23M3+REQ_SALES_FMC_23M3))))
    end  Rev0_prognoz
```

Comment: Поправьте форматирование. Скрины не видны, их нужно вставить картинкой.

Comment: замените `avg(RT0M_23M2)` на `nvl(avg(RT0M_23M2),0)` и включите его во все суммы

Comment: Спасибо за вариант.  Я данный вариант пробовала, просто тогда выходит ошибка Ora-01476: Делить на 0 нельзя.                                                                                                                                        Т.К. сумма по некоторым строкам выходит 0.

Comment: Попробуйте сперва подсчитать средние и суммы нарастающим итогом через оконные функции и только потом писать CASE ....

Comment: `сумма по некоторым строкам выходит 0` - деление `a/b` нужно заменять на `a/nullif(b,0)`